# Trouble on selecting auto-suggest and moving it into the textbox

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**Note:-** Here, the Listitems are not under **div** class

Could able to locate the element but the select function is not working.

**HTML used:**

```html
 <head>
 <body id="data-search" class="hassidebar">
   ‌<ul id="material-result-list" style="top: 183px; left: 396.5px; width: 270px; display: block;">
     <li>
     <li>
     <li>
    <a>nitrate/0.2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
     <li>
   </ul>
```

**CODE used:**

*Try 1:*

```java
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'material-result-list')]/li"));
listItems.get(2).click();
```

*Try 2:*

```java
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElement(By.id("material-result-list")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
listItems.get(2).click();
```

(used more combinations, please help on this)

I could retrieve the auto-suggest texts using **getText()** method **[so it confirms that there are no issues on locating the element]**
But has trouble on select them and placing under text field for search

```java
List<WebElement> link = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'material-result-list')]/li"));
String secondoption = link.get(2).getText();
System.out.println(secondoption);
```

Comment: <li>  <a>nitrate/0.2</a>   </li>   | I missed to specify anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above script is trying to click on tag `"li"` and not on anchor tag `"a"`;
Here, the **getText()** method of tag `"li"` will return text.

So, we need to click on specific **anchor  tag**.

**Solution:**

```
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElement(By.id("material-result-list")).findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
listItems.get(2).click();
```